# Using ng-repeat twice in view using same controller

Tags: angularjs

I'm using one controller for a view that looks like this

```
<div>
<div ng-repeat="blah in blah1">
</div>
<div ng-repeat="blah in blah2">
</div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the second time ng-repeat is used, it seems to duplicate what was seen in the first repeat. I have confirmed that **blah1** is in fact different from **blah2**. I'm not sure as to why the second ng-repeat goes through items in blah1.

Any clues?

Thanks!

Comment: " I have confirmed that blah2 is in fact different from blah2." i hope you meant to say blah1 and blah2 are different.

Comment: they can't be different if you see the same thing, or there is a logic flaw in your code somewhere. Please provide enough code to replicate

Answer (score 3):

maybe the ng-repeat for blah2 is included inside the ng-repeat of blah1, so it repeats blah1 content everytime blah2 is iterated.

otherwise should work fine

```
<div ng-app='bla'>

<div  ng-controller='ctrl'>
    <div ng-repeat="blah in blah1">
        <span>{{blah}}</span>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="blah in blah2">
        <span>{{blah}}</span>
    </div>
</div>

</div>

<script>
    angular.module('bla', [])
.controller('ctrl', ctrl);

function ctrl($scope){

    $scope.blah1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    $scope.blah2 = [21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29]

}
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hsdcpk2x/1/

Answer (score 1):

ng-repeat goes just over all the items in blah1 and blah2. If the second ng-repeat duplicates blah1 then they are in fact the same. You should post more code so we can get to the actual issue.

Answer (score -1):

use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end
hope it would solve your issue

Comment: Please edit your post to show the actual code you're recommending.